# Zoom chartjs with many X values

Tags: javascript, html, chart.js, chart.js2

I'm facing an issue with zoom in `chart.js` when the chart has many X Values.

The zoom option is working fine, but when I have many values in `X axis`, the zoom has a stranger behaviour not zooming very well this axis.

I've create two charts, one with less data, just check how the `X axis` works fine, and another one with many data, you can see that it becomes unstable to make the right zoom.

Chart few data (working fine): https://jsfiddle.net/lguima/y3n8bzk2/

Chart many data (strange X zoom): https://jsfiddle.net/lguima/e6nd4two/

The options for zoom I'm using are:

```
     zoom: {
        enabled: true,
        drag: false,
        mode: "xy",
        limits: {
           max: 10,
           min: 0.5
        }
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue: https://github.com/chartjs/chartjs-plugin-zoom/issues/306

One possible workaround is to set a custom zoom increment/step in the `onZoom` handler, and apply different zoom parameters for each axis.